# Same script working differently in 2 script editors

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

Premise: I have not a problem with algorythms or syntax or method and so on, for this reason I apologize not to report scripts or piece of it. 
But I am in a mistery.

I have a Form for booking medical appointments, filled on line by patients, that feeds a Sheet where appointments are reported. The sheet is used only by the doctor to have the view of his engagements. The form suggests to the patients a list of days and hourly slots, by a ListItem of open time intervals (i.e.: Wed March, 3 hh 11 - 11:20 am ). The sheet (triggered *on submit* of the form) drives the automatic update of the List Item of the Google Form, to be proposed to the next patient requiring an appointment.
One function in one script for all, it works perfectly.

Now, I would like to give the doctor the possibility to manage the table of the appointment (the sheet), editing the cells of the table itself. But so doing the List Item of the time slots in the Form has to be updated every time the table is edited (triggering *on edit*).

So, to the aim:
1) I took the piece of my script in charge of updating the Form, which became a new function in the same script editor as I developed the primary function. The new function works perfectly when it runs from the script editor of the Form.
2) **I copy INTEGRALLY the above script in the script editor of the sheet and...a *for* loop does not work as expected, in any way it does not work as it does in the Form environment.**

Note: every files are opened by ID and no methods are invoked on "active" file.
Thanks

Comment: I am getting reasoning about Timezone...The "for" loop I mentioned refers to the value of a cell containing a date, from which I pick the day of week by the .getDay() method.

Comment: And I finally solved. It was a problem arising from the Timezone management. In facts, Guide says:
"New scripts default to the owner's time zone, but the script's time zone can be changed by clicking File > Project properties in the script editor."
I did, problem evaporated and I found my peace.

Answer (score 0):

Posting for documentation purposes; OP found the answer, as per their comment:

And I finally solved. It was a problem arising from the Timezone management. In facts, Guide says: "New scripts default to the owner's time zone, but the script's time zone can be changed by clicking File > Project properties in the script editor." I did, problem evaporated and I found my peace.